# JSF 2 Prerenderview Listener Not Called When Page Called From Action Method Outcome

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, managed-bean

I am calling a page from another with a prerender view event in an f:metadata element.

If I navigate to page using `<h:link>` it works and calls the listener method.

However if I navigate to the page using an outcome from the action method of a managed bean belonging to the calling page, the listener designated in the prerenderview doesn't get called (as it does if called by a link). It does navigate to the second page, just no listener call.

I would really prefer to call from the action method because I use it to do some work and place a variable in the session map for the called page to use. I'm not sure how to achieve the same thing using a link. The object can be rather large... kb not Mb but still not something I want to put in the request.

I've tried making the managed bean of the calling page request scoped and view scoped.

Is it not possible to get a prerenderview to fire if it is called from a managed bean outcome? As I said, I got it to work from a link.

```
<body>
    <ui:define name="metadata">
        <f:view>
            <f:metadata>
                <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{businessBean.init}" />
            </f:metadata>
        </f:view>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:composition template="#{navigationprops.soulard_2col_uprefs_template}">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ui:composition tag trim everything outside it, so facelets compiler doesn't have the chance to read the code. Instead, you should use ui:decorate, but remember f:metadata tag only works on the top level page, not inside the template client. For example:

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="hotid" 
       value="#{hotelBooking.hotelId}" 
       converter="javax.faces.Long"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{hotelBooking.selectHotel}"/>
</f:metadata>
<ui:decorate template="template.xhtml">
   <ui:define name="content">
   <!-- ... -->
   </ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
</ui:composition>
```

See [This example](https://github.com/lu4242/performance-comparison-java-web-frameworks/blob/master/perfbench-code/myfaces-jpa/src/main/webapp/hotel.xhtml) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other answer and this is the only thing I got to work... that is mimic a link in the action method by calling redirect programmatically.

```
public void editArticle(Article article) {
    FacesContext fcontext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext context = fcontext.getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = context.getSessionMap();
    sessionMap.put("articleId", article.getArticleId());
    String urlString = navBundle.getString("ARTICLE_EDITOR");
    String url = context.encodeActionURL(fcontext.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(fcontext, urlString));
    try {
        context.redirect(url);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ELSLogger.LOG(Level.SEVERE, this.getClass().getName(), "checkEligableToLogin", "Couldn't Redirect to: " + url);
    }
}
```

Now it turns out I changed my mind on the prerender view, but this is done and works so I'll refactor later. But in case anyone wants to see working code that will call another page programmatically from a backing bean, here it is. FWIW, "ARTICLE_EDITOR" is a variable holding a url starting from the context-root.

Comment: Your concrete problem is just caused by the wrong way of using Facelets.